# How to use 32-bit Assembly functions in 64-bit Qt app?

Tags: c++, qt, assembly

I have written some arithmetic operations in Assembly *.s file in 32-bit architecture and I'd like to use them in Qt application built by Qt 5.10.1 GCC 64bit kit. Creating a simple C++ program I used following command to build executable file:

```
g++ -o prog main.cpp float_operations.s -m32
```

Now I can't figure out how to emplace building *.s file into building process of Qt app to make functions from *.s file usable in my Qt app.

I've found some solutions to include x64 assembly files but in this case is strongly necessary for me to use 32-bit assembly :(

Thank you.

Comment: Short answer: don't do that. Rewrite the code as 64 bit or if it's a standalone program then invoke it using `exec*`. Or, rewrite it in C++ using gcc vector support or intrinsics. If you really insist you could set up a 32 bit code segment but that would be a lot of headache.

Comment: "I have written some arithmetic operations in Assembly" - *Why*? Prefer writing your code in readable, portable C++ and let the compiler worry about generating efficient machine code - it probably does a better job and even if it doesn't, the difference is unlikely to actually matter.

Comment: @JesperJuhl It's part of my homework. I have to create some functions in Assembly and use them in C++ program.

Comment: Don't mix 32-bit and 64-bit.  Not going to work.

Comment: Did your homework specify 32 bit assembly? I would be surprised if it did. Rewriting code mostly doing arithmetic as 64 bit should be a trivial matter. Also you could of course compile your Qt application as 32 bit.

Comment: If you enabled optimization when you compile, like `g++ -O3 -march=native`, you wouldn't need to hand-write in asm for performance.  And/or looking at the asm output might be a good example of how to do things.  If you want 64-bit code-gen to use x87, you could use `-mfpmath=387`, but that won't change the calling convention...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 options:

- Rewrite the assembly to 64-bit (any language with a 64-bit assembler or compiler) so it can load into a 64-bit process.
- Change the application to 32-bit so the 32-bit assembly can run in-process.
- Run two processes, one 32-bit and one 64-bit, and use interprocess communication.

Comment: For completeness: 4. create a 32 bit code segment :)

Comment: @Jester No, just no.  Yes, I've done it before.  No, it's not worth it.

Comment: 4. port the assembly to C++ (with intrinsics if needed), so it can be optimized for whatever calling convention you're using, etc. etc.

Comment: @PeterCordes: That's really falls into #1 -- rewriting the code to run 64-bit.  I'll add a note that mentions that the language can change in that process.  Although according the comments, OP is required to use assembly.

Comment: I've just changed application to 32-bit and that solved the problem. Thanks for help! :)